# what's the best Firebird IDE?

Tags: database, development-environment, firebird

Simple question. I'm considering Firebird and SQLite for an upcoming project. SQLite has SQLite Administrator, which is pretty good but gets +1M because it has autocomplete. But Firebird supports FKs, so I'm more comfortable with it. I'm leaning toward Firebird right now.

What is your favorite Firebird IDE and why?

Edit: Personally, I'll be gravitating toward the free ones because I'm not making much on this project. But I'll leave the question as is.

Comment: all: it'll take me a while to come up with an answer for this one, be patient.

Comment: https://www.ibphoenix.com/download/tools/admin   this is from the firebird official site.  there are 15 ide with their capability described shortly . some can do backup restore. some can modify table scheme

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like [IBExpert](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Main.IBExpert) for Firebird (or Interbase). They have a free personal edition.

Comment: The only one that's complete at this time and worked. But I didn't test it thoroughly because I decided against FB.

Answer (score 17):

Test all this !

- IBEasy
  http://www.marc-grange.net/telecharger.htm *
- Firebird Editor Pro https://www.texteditor.pro/firebird/ *
- IBExpert http://www.ibexpert.com *
- Database Workbench
  http://www.upscene.com *
- FireFace http://www.fireface.eu
- Firebird Maestro
  http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/firebird/maestro/
- EMS SQL Mananger
  http://sqlmanager.net/products/ibfb/manager *
- BlazeTop
  http://www.devrace.com/en/blazetop/
- Firebird Development Studio
  http://www.sqlly.com/
- FlameRobin http://www.flamerobin.org/ *
- Kevora IDE
  http://kevora.sourceforge.net/
- IBWebAdmin http://www.ibwebadmin.net/ *
- RazorSQL http://www.razorsql.com/
- SQuirel SQL
  http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ *
- OD Web ISQL
  http://www.e-naxos.com/dnlManager.aspx?GROUP=6 *
- DBeaver https://dbeaver.io *

For me the best is **IBExpert** and after Database Workbench because they have stored procedure debugger

(*) means free or have free version (personal...)

Comment: To complemlement the list. HQBird Enterprise is said ti include some "SQL Studio" https://ib-aid.com/en/hqbird-features and there is one from SQLLY https://www.sqlly.com/ and there is RedExpert at https://reddatabase.ru/en/products/

Comment: Official (?) IDEs list - https://firebirdsql.org/en/third-party-tools/

Answer (score 10):

I would not want to enter it into a contest for best Firebird IDE (yet), but you could look into [FlameRobin](http://www.flamerobin.org) for a free multi-platform administration program for Firebird. It has auto completion, starts as fast as no other GUI tool I know of, and the price should be right for you.

Comment: FlameRobin ins't better than IBExpert.

Comment: @DanielGrillo what makes IBExpert better for you?

Comment: @Bas Nowadays I don't know if IBExpert is better than FlameRobin. This comment is 'very' old.

Answer (score 7):

Databaseworkbench - does everthing - SQL Developer's heaven

Answer (score 3):

I have used the free version of EMS SQL Manager. It is a great IDE with all the features I ever need and compares with something like Management Studio for SQL Server. [Link](http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/ibfb/manager)

Comment: I spent about 20 mins looking at this one, stopped when it couldn't create a database: "can't find procedure isc_dsql_execute_immediate fbclient.dll". Not saying it's bad, but if it encounters a critical issue that soon, I'm gonna move on to the next one.

Comment: That error message isn't exact, it's what i typed in to google when I hit the fault. Didn't find anything on google about it. Tried the other dll and got the same fault.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you [Firebird Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/firebird/maestro/). It's not free but what you get for the price of a license is a very good product, especially because you can perform most of your tasks visually.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from an IDE for Firebird, you may want to take a look at [Sinática Monitor for Firebird](http://www.sinatica.com).
It's great for finding bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for [AnySQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/anysql/maestro/)

1. Freeware

   Able to work with Firebird and SQLite databases at the same time

The producer also offers a tool for SQLite (SQLite Maestro) that SUPPORTS FOREIGN KEYS (with referential integrity triggers) but it has only 30-day free trial (costs about $70).

Comment: 1. It works in 2018. :) 2. It is free. 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FlameRobin is simple, easy to use, and has a small footprint. Additionally, it's free.