# How to test my Firebird SQL queries

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm in the process of learning SQL, and I need a way of verifying that my SQL queries are valid (i.e. no syntax errors). I also would like to check what results they yield on a test database of my choosing and structure.

I'm using embedded firebird in my C# .NET application, so I don't really have any tools to work with. Anyone have any tips? Perhaps there are SQL administrators/query IDEs out there that work with Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) personal or [DatabaseWorkbench](http://www.upscene.com) Lite

check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992943/firebird-frontend-gui) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490039/whats-the-best-firebird-ide)